# CoffeeScript callback parameter becomes Object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

My callback function is being wrapped as an object when process into JavaScript. The browser throws this error because of it:

*Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function*

The CoffeeScript:

```
startCamera: ->
    @media = $('#camera').getUserMedia {},
    success: (obj) ->
        console.log obj
        return
return
```

The Output:

```
startCamera: function() {
    this.media = $('#camera').getUserMedia({}, {
        success: function(obj) {
            console.log(obj);
        }
    });
}
```

How can I build a regular anonymous function for the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly you want to pass an anonymous function as the second parameter.

To do that you will need to get rid of the text `success:` so that your coffeescript looks as follows:

```
startCamera: ->
    @media = $('#camera').getUserMedia {},
    (obj) ->
        console.log obj
        return
    return
```

Comment: Perfect! For readability, is there any way to name anonymous functions inline , or does it need to be declared before it's passed in?

Comment: @theLucre if readability is a concern you could always add a coffeescript comment above the function like `# success:`.